# Which comes first after picking up shel rosh: talis or tefilin?

Tags: tefilin, mistakes, tallit-gadol, priorities

If a person picked up his tefilin before his talis, he puts on his tefilin first (Shulchan Orech OC 25:1). Additionally, if a person picked up his shel Rosh before his shel yad (ibid. :6) he puts down the shel rosh and puts on the shel yad.

What happens if a person picks up his shel rosh before his talis; does he

A) put it down and don his shel yad first since he has engaged with his tefilin he should not switch to his talis?

B) put it down and now that he's holding nothing he's effectively starting from scratch and should put on his talis?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81409/759

Answer (score -1):

The Biur Halacha in Mishna Berura Siman 25 seems to say clearly that as long as it's in front of you, even if not specifically being held in your hand, it would still require tefillin first. So putting down the shel rosh shouldn't make a difference, since in most cases both the shel yad and the shel rosh are together in their own bag/case that would mean that the shel yad was also taken according to the Biur Halacha.

> אבל כ"ז אין שייך לדינא דהא לדעת המחבר דנקטינן כוותיה וכן פסקו כמעט כל האחרונים [הלבוש והב"ח והט"ז והנ"א והארה"ח דלא כמ"א] אין חילוק בזה שהוא סובר דאפילו אם התפלין מונחין בתוך כיסן שייך בזה אין מעבירין. ובאמת פשוט הוא לענ"ד דגם המ"א מודה בזה ודלא כהפמ"ג דעד כאן לא קשרי המ"א אלא היכא שהתפלין מונחין בכיס בפ"ע שלא נגע בהן כלל בידו רק ע"י כיס וא"א להניחן ע"י כיס משא"כ בזה שהם ממש בידו או שלפי הושטת ידו הם מזומנין לפניו תחלה מה יועיל במה שהם עדיין בתוך הכיס

In a case where the Tefillin were separate and only the shel rosh was moved while the shel yad remained in its original place then this would not be relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the conclusion you're drawing to our case.

Comment: Option B seems to be saying that by putting down the shel rosh he's effectively starting over. However his tefillin is still the first in regards to the tallis just as much as it was before he picked up the shel rosh, and the biur halacha holds that it comes first even if it's still in the bag

Comment: Does that all depend where the shel yad is currently? You are just discussing what happens when you start over, but you haven't yet proved you start over and aren't 'locked in' tefillin first.

Comment: Oh, I assumed the shel yad and shel rosh were together. You mean to say the OP was only in  a case where the Tefillin were separate and he picked up the shel rosh without ever even moving the shel yad at all?

Comment: The OP's case is stated generally. Any relevant factors and their various outcomes should seemingly be spelled out in the answer.

Comment: @ Chatzkel Current day, the talis and tefilin are always both munachim lefanecha. I’m just talking where he simply reached in and picked up the shel rosh first. He didn’t touch the shel yad, didn’t pick up the bag, etc

Comment: [Kaf HaChaim 25:7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8140&st=&pgnum=94) in the name of the Arizal one should always put on Talis first, even if they picked up the Tefilin first.

Comment: The Chazon Ish says that by keeping the Tallis on top of the tefillin in the bag, the tefillin wouldn't be considered Munachim lefonecha

Comment: Regardless - what would be if the shel yad was touched first?

Comment: You mean if he picked up the shel yad? Then he puts on tefillin first then the tallis. That's the Shulchan Aruch case

Comment: Sorry meant shel rosh. Typo